# localization of mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I am working with an MVC4 application that needs to be localized for a large number of countries. Therefore I need to localize the views, string etc. What is the standard practice for localizing an mvc application? Is it one resource file with a particular naming convention to highlight views? or 1 resource file per view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you consider the **localization** of **MVC App,** you should consider below mentioned scenarios.

1. Views validation
2. Simple culture switching mechanism
3. Model Validation messages localization
4. DisplayName attribute localization
5. OutputCache and Localization

For get more details of above scenarios check [**ASP.NET MVC  Localization complete guide**](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)

And [**Scott Hanselman Blog Post**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.